# How to correctly make sets draggable in Raphael

Tags: svg, raphael, drag

One often wants to make a set of objects in Raphael draggable, but using `.transform()` to do so can be maddening. Say you start like this:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
var set = paper.set();
set.push(paper.circle(100,100,35), paper.circle(150,150,15));    
set.attr("fill", "orange");
set.data("myset", set);

set.drag(
    function(dx, dy, x, y, e) {
        this.data('myset').transform("T" + dx + "," + dy);
    },
    function(x, y, e) {},
    function(e) {}
);
```

If you [try this out](http://jsfiddle.net/cLtHA/), you see it works once. But if you drag, stop, then drag again, it resets the position to 0,0 relative to the original position, as you'd expect from `.transform().` No good.

A variant of this question has been touched on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735731/raphael-moving-sets), and the respondent suggested prepending transforms with "...". That's all fine and good, but for two things:

- you still have to track previous position, since you don't want to
  translate by (dx,dy) on every call of `dragmove`, which will send
  the objects flying off the screen.
- I worry about creating a monster
  transform if an object is dragged many times. (Though maybe I
  shouldn't.)

My tentative solution is to track the offset from the original positioning in another key/value pair, like so:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);

var set = paper.set();
set.push(
    paper.circle(100,100,35),
    paper.circle(150,150,15)
);    
set.attr("fill", "orange");
set.data("myset", set);
set.data("position", [0,0]);
var current_position = [0,0];

set.drag(
    function(dx, dy, x, y, e) {
        this.data('myset').transform("T" + (this.data("position")[0] + dx) + "," + (this.data("position")[1] + dy));
        current_position = [dx,dy];
    },
    function(x, y, e) {

    },
    function(e) {
        this.data('myset').data("position", [
            this.data("position")[0] += current_position[0],
            this.data("position")[1] += current_position[1]
        ]);
    }
);
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9jPy/).

It works, but it feels incredibly sloppy. I must be missing something obvious, right?

Comment: As the respondent to the variant question you mention above, I would like to point out that I didn't entirely approve of my own suggestion =)  I have found this to be a recurrent problem and I'm sure that there must be a cleaner solution; I'm just not sure what it might be yet.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to your last variant:

```
var onmove = function (dx,dy){
    this.transform(this.default_transform+'T'+dx+','+dy); 
},
  onstart = function (){
    this.default_transform = this.transform();
},
  onend = function(){
    this.default_transform = this.transform();
};

set.drag(onmove, onstart, onend);
```

Don't worry it won't create a long long line of transformations because Raphael converts everything to one whole matrix transformation so it doesn't build up each time you move an object.